# Error in gridview trying to show data of only the current user

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

The C# code:

```
string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DinoData.mdf;";
str += "Integrated Security= True";

SqlConnection c;
c = new SqlConnection(str);

if (Show.Text == "all" || Show.Text == "All" || Show.Text == "all table" || Show.Text == "All table" || Show.Text == "All Table" || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Show.Text))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    String req;
    req = "SELECT * FROM [User] Where Username = "+Session["CurentUserid"];

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, c);
    da.Fill(dt);

    datagrid.DataSource = dt;
    datagrid.DataBind();
}
else
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Show.Text))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        String req;
        req = Show.Text+ " Where Username = " + Session["CurentUserid"];

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, c);
        da.Fill(dt);

        datagrid.DataSource = dt;
        datagrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid column name 'Niss'.

Please help, `Niss` is the id of one of my users

Comment: where is this error occurring? By the way you could change all your conditions in the first `if` to `Show.Text.ToLower().Contains("all")`

Comment: I bet the username stored in the session variable is Niss, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical error caused by not using a parameterized query. You have forgotten to put the username value between single quotes so your Niss user has been confused as a column name

```
req = "SELECT * FROM [User] Where Username = @user";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, c);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["CurentUserid"];
da.Fill(dt);
```

More in depth: `UserName` is a text column and thus if you want to search a value on this column you need to put the value between single quotes.
However fixing the problem adding a couple of quotes

```
Where Username = '"+Session["CurentUserid"] + "'"
```

just changes the problem because if you have a user with a single quote in its user name you are facing again a syntax error. The only correct way is to use a parameterized query as I have shown.

I leave the discussion about Sql Injection and all the problems you could face in your code in the else part (where you use a whole textbox to build your query to [this well known answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: Good to be of help, but I think you are on a dangerous path. The else part and the use of Show.Text is a very big security risk. Read the answers posted in the link above.